# Retrofit- handle invalid data in search option

Tags: android, retrofit2, weather-api

I'm creating weather app where I'm giving option to user to search weather by any city. when user enter valid city name my app work fine , but when user enter invalid string ex: **asndfs,bdfbsj**  then my app terminate .

how to handle this? so that my app wont terminate **instead give message to user saying that please enter valid city name**

here is my code when user enter string and i make call to openWeatherApi.

```
private void getWeatherDataByCity(String city) {
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(Constants.CITY, city);
    params.put(Constants.UNIT, Constants.UNITS);
    params.put(Constants.APP_ID, Constants.API_KEY);
    RetrofitClient.getData(params).enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            cityName.setText(response.body().getCityName() + "," + response.body().getSys().getCounty());
            String temperature = String.format("%.2f", response.body().getMain().getTemp()) + "°C";
            temp.setText(temperature);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

**Json response when user enter valid city:**

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 77.22,
        "lat": 28.65
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 721,
            "main": "Haze",
            "description": "haze",
            "icon": "50d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 305.15,
        "pressure": 1008,
        "humidity": 43,
        "temp_min": 305.15,
        "temp_max": 305.15
    },
    "visibility": 3000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 5.7,
        "deg": 110
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 20
    },
    "dt": 1525413600,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 7809,
        "message": 0.0996,
        "country": "IN",
        "sunrise": 1525392476,
        "sunset": 1525440495
    },
    "id": 1273294,
    "name": "Delhi",
    "cod": 200
}
```

**Json respone when user enter invalid city:**

```
{
    "cod": "404",
    "message": "city not found"
}
```

**Result.java**

```
public class Result {
    @SerializedName("main")
    private Temprature main;
    @SerializedName("sys")
    private Sys sys;
    @SerializedName("cod")
    private int cod;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String cityName;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    private List<Weather> weather = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public Temprature getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public Sys getSys() {
        return sys;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public int getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: use try catch into onResponse method.when you press "sdfsdf" then it should return null.

Comment: @SaurabhVadhva when i press "dfdfsf" then in repsone i get  `{
    "cod": "404",
    "message": "city not found"
}`

Comment: when proper result coming then which type of Json response . please share it.

Comment: @SaurabhVadhva this link (http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=delhi&appid=YOUR_API_KEY)

Comment: Please check the answer me as well as "Alexandru Sandu" both are working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app terminates because it is looking for a json field that does not exist because of the wrong name. try this:

```
 public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            if (response.code() == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cityName.setText(response.message());
                temp.setText("0" + "°C");
            } else {
                cityName.setText(response.body().getCityName() + "," +
                        response.body().getSys().getCounty());
                String temperature = String.format("%.2f", response.body().getMain().getTemp()) + "°C";
                temp.setText(temperature);
            }
        }
```

EDIT: I don't know how to take the json from a Response of type result and right now i cant keep looking but all you need todo is check if the "cod" of your response is different from 404 before you try to parse the json

Comment: Its god we worked it out in the end and learned a few things on the way

Answer (score 1):

Please use this

```
public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response){
try {
    cityName.setText(response.body().getCityName() + "," + 
    response.body().getSys().getCounty());
        String temperature = String.format("%.2f", 
    response.body().getMain().getTemp()) + "°C";
        temp.setText(temperature);
} catch(Exception e {               
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Won't work either, the way of getting the JSON that you used is for Response<ResponseBody> not for Response<Result>. That is why it is not working. It is the same mistake that i made in my answer and i don't know exacly how to get the json from a Response<Result>

Comment: @chandmohd please post your Result model as well.

Comment: @chandmohd please check my answer again.

Comment: @AlexandruSandu I have class called Result which is managed all the data from Json thatswhy i used Response<Result> instead Response<ResponseBody>

Comment: @SaurabhVadhva please check i have added Result class

Comment: @Saurabh Vadhva Nice little hack there, it should work tho.

Comment: @SaurabhVadhva thanks man that works , application is not terminating but i want show some message to user so that he can retry and get weather result . how would i do that?

Comment: Anything Toasted on the Screen?